# How can I get the P/Invoke definitions for Windows API functions?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, pinvoke, dllimport

I want to use functions from the Win32 API in my .NET application, but I don't know the signature of the methods declared in the DLL files. If I use `DllImport`, I have to provide a definition of the method in order to use it as an "extern method".

Or is there another way to do this?

Comment: You need to accept more answers.

Answer (score 7):

You could have a look at [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/), it is a collection of methods supported by various Win32 apis. Also it contains programs which can generate `DllImport` signatures if you have the C-style header.

Answer (score 1):

Most Win32 API signatures are listed [here](http://pinvoke.net/).

Or you could try [DLL Export Viewer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html).